# Old partition to create new partition

Tags: grub2, partitioning, gparted

A few years ago I started using Ubuntu because somehow my computer was unable to work with Windows. Ubuntu worked perfectly since then, except for today. Today I turned on my computer and had this problem:

```
boot: run-init: /sbin/init: No such file or directory
```

Since I have all of my data backed up and in reality I hadn't installed any relevant programs on my computer, I just decided to avoid all the problems and reinstall Ubuntu.
I was expecting to get all of my files erased, but turns out they were in a different partition/drive that is the size of 700GB, and my "home" partition is the size of 46GB. Don't ask me why, I just click OK in everything.

I think 46 is way too little, so I would like to increase the size of it, as I have a lot of space in the 700GB. However, every time I try to resize the 700GB, GParted says it is dangerous, so I don't know what to do. I had the impression that the 700GB partition was just on the past and contained no system files.
My question is:
Can I resize the partition of 700GB without screwing the GRUB and have to reinstall it? I ask because it sounds difficult to reinstall the GRUB and I am in reality a newbie who just have Ubuntu because it works well with my computer.

Is there a way to use the 700GB partition as my "home" partition to install programs and everything?

Side note: I don't use windows AT ALL in this computer, it just got screwed and never ever worked again (I think I even deleted it to create the 700GB partition).

Thank you!

Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: I think you have it backwards. It looks like the 46G partition is your / root partition, where all of your programs get installed. The 700G partition looks like your /home partition, where all of your personal files are stored. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sda4` partition (~46GB) is definitely /(root).

The `sda7` (~700GB) is not /home (/home is also under /) and it's not in use by the currently installed Ubuntu; maybe a leftover from a previous installation.

And you still have NTFS (Windows) partitions there.

Whatever you decide to do, **DO NOT TOUCH SDA2** (EFI partition).

That said, you can remove all NTFS partitions if you really don't need Windows. Then, in order to maximize the resources in a sane way, here are a few suggestions:

- Having a swap partition of +130GB is a huge waste of space. With +8GB RAM you barely need 2GB! Right-click and `swapoff` then resize accordingly and move it to the right.
- Backup `sda7`'s contents if applicable and remove the partition altogether.
- Resize `sda4` in order to use all the remaining unallocated space.

Notes: The above suggestions assume you already deleted the NTFS parttions. You need to use GParted in a live session. Partitions cannot be "in use" (mounted) for this operations. Even in a live session `swap` will be used hence the need to `swapoff`. Finally, there's no point in removing `sda1` base there's very little to gain in terms of space and you shouldn't be moving the EFI partition anyway (and to make use of that space you would need to move all the other partitions to the left with increased risk of data loss).

Comment: I might have done it differently. If you delete the two NTFS partitions, the OP won't get access to the OEM's diag and recovery software. I agree about the swap space. Since we don't know what's on sda7, I'd investigate that more, and then maybe turn it into /home, edit the default /home location, edit /etc/fstab, and copy over anything from /home on sda4 to the new /home on sda7. Cheers, Al

Comment: Also, in a live running system, in gparted, you can issue a swapoff, manipulate the swap partition (delete/resize/move/new), and then issue a swapon command. /etc/fstab may need to get edited with a new UUID if you recreated the swap partition. Cheers, Al

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. Particularly to CelticWarrior (I avoided any changes on my computer because I didn't want to screw it during the final month of classes). So what I did at the end was: 1) using the USB session, deleted the partition of 700 GB and expanded the SD4 partition. I was going to resize the partition for Swap, but I got scared that I would screw up, so I left it as it is. In addition, I have plenty of space for everything, so I do not think the 130 GB was a big problem. I also left everything else (including the NTFS) intact.